# adding new column to groupby result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Note: I saw all related issues to group by output, and I changed my code accordingly but did not get the required output.

I created test data set after group by with one of the column in the data set. Then I tried below to get desired output.

```
fd = pd.read_csv("C:/......\Test.csv")

coder_gr = fd.groupby(["CIQ"])
print(coder_gr.first())

for x, y in coder_gr:
    y.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(y.columns)
    y.columns = y.columns.add_categories(["Duplicate"])
    y["Duplicate"] = y.Date.duplicated()

"""also tried with below code:"""

for x, y in coder_gr:
    y.assign(Duplicate = y.Date.duplicated().values, index=y.index)
```

But getting below empty output or error (Setting with Copy Warning):

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples, and then provide the input, as well as the expected output, **as text** in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the third line `coder_gr.reset_index()` should do the job.

Comment: After using the above code, I am getting error message as : AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'reset_index'   @SevenOfNine